# Make ingresses/services publicly DNS resolvable on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dns, coredns

We have a GKE cluster set up on Google Cloud and we want new ingress routes to be automatically resolvable under the according subdomain.

**We have a subdomain** (lets say app-dev.company.com) which already **resolves to the public IP** of our ingress controller (Traefik) and when I create a service "hello-world" on k8s, it should be automatically publicly resolvable under hello-world.app-dev.company.com as well.

I used to work with a cluster on Azure before, where it was simply a matter of configuring CoreDNS with stub domain and upstream DNS and it just worked after that. Now Google still uses kube-dns for some reason; I tried configuring the stub domain "app-dev.company.com" in kube-dns and installing CoreDNS (and scaling kube-dns down to 0) but that did not work and broke some other things, so I rolled it back.

I also looked into Googles Cloud DNS service (since Google recommends it), but I don't want that hard vendor lock in tbh, also I'm not sure if that even does what I want.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear exactly where the issue is.  Why exactly do you need a stub domain?

Comment: I want the cluster to be responsible for it's own subdomains. This is the way we had it configured in Azure with no issue at all using CoreDNS. Once configured, it makes my life as a cluster user a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth, but trying to figure out the best solution here.  I'm pretty sure you guys must be using Azure Hybrid DNS for this.   So let's say you deploy an ingress route for "newapp.app-dev.company.com".   How do you create a DNS record for "newapp.app-dev.company.com" ?

Comment: I'm quite certain we used CoreDNS and CoreDNS itself was publicly available uner port 53. The DNS record was thus created autoamtically once a new service/ingress was created.

Answer (score -1):

A few things:

- You will need to reserve a [global static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static).
- You will need to create/update your DNS record to point to that IP address.
- There is a 1-1 mapping between GKE Ingress and a GCP external load balancer.  This means that you cannot have multiple Ingress resources mapped to the same external IP.
- If you want to have multiple applications behind the same Ingress, you can configure your Ingress resource to use path based or name based virtual hosting to route to multiple backend applications.

**Reserve a static IP address:**

```
gcloud compute addresses create ${ADDRESS} --global
```

Replace ${ADDRESS} with any name you like.

**Annotate your Ingress resource to tell the load balancer to use the static IP created above**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloweb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ${ADDRESS}
```

Replace ${ADDRESS} with the name of the static IP created in the previous step

**Configure multiple backend apps**

[Path-based](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: multi-app-fanout
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ${ADDRESS}
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /app2/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app2
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /app3/*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: app3
            port:
              number: 8080
```

You would access your apps as follows:

- app-dev.company.com
- app-dev.company.com/app2
- app-dev.company.com/app3

[Name-based virtual hosting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: multi-app-virtual
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ${ADDRESS}
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.app-dev.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1
            port:
              number: 8080
  - host: app2.app-dev.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: app2
            port:
              number: 8080
  - host: ap32.app-dev.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: app3
            port:
              number: 8080
```

You would access your apps as follows:

- app1.app-dev.company.com
- app2.app-dev.company.com
- app3.app-dev.company.com

**Configure DNS records**
If you choose to do path-based routing, then you just need to add a single DNS A record which maps *app-dev.company.com* to the global IP address created above.

If you choose name-based virtual hosting, you'll need to create a wildcard record mapping **.app-dev.company.com* to the global IP address.

See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip for more info.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. We have the pub IP and the A record resolves to that. We don't need multiple ingresses, just one. I was talking about ingress routes, not ingress controllers. I'm looking to do name based routing with Traefik. All subdomains should in fact point to the same v4 IP, but Traefik will route the request accordingly. I could create a wildcard DNS record, but I want to have it work either with AXFR or our cluster DNS being authoritative for the stub domain. I just don't know how as I'm more of a k8s user than admin.

Comment: I see you updated your original question (at least I don't recall seeing Traefik when I read the original post)

Comment: The best solution for this on GKE today is to use Cloud DNS with external-dns:   https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/gke.md